# iPhone view is 3/4 grey, could be rotated incorrectly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

This problem has just come up when I cleaned all targets and soft resetted (held home & power for about 10 seconds) my iPod Touch (2nd gen). It looks like the view might be rotated portrait.

Here is a pic of the problem:

[alt text http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/5582/iphonescreenshot.png](http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/5582/iphonescreenshot.png)

The view is linked to a XIB file, and I setup landscape in interface builder. I also use

```
<key>UIInterfaceOrientation</key>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
```

in the info.plist file, and use

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

in the main view controller and the sub view controller.

My view hierarchy is: App delegate Window (Linked to App Delegate) -> MainViewController View (Linked to MainViewController) -> SubViewController View (Linked to SubViewController).

Thanks,

Niall.

EDIT: I'm trying to achieve a full black full screen view. The width and height look OK in IB. (480,320)

Answer (score 1):

Check your spring-and-struts in IB; without knowing what you're TRYING to achieve here, it's hard to recommend a course of action. I imagine you'd like fullscreen, either black or gray, so most likely you've not set the view in question to be full-width and -height.